# python 3.4 , django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I am new at learning Django, I am using django-1.9.6. By default I was using python 2.7 and for this django app I have installed 3.4 and run the terminal typing

```
manage.py shell
```

When ever I tried to import something from my models in terminal , it throughs this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/farhad/PycharmProjects/website/music/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Album(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Did you imported some models in your settings file? Try importing your settings from a normal python shell and paste the result.

Comment: You have a model called Album in an app called music but music is not in your INSTALLED_APPS of settings.py

Answer (score 1):

If you're just opening the Python shell, you won't have access to anything in Django. Try `manage.py shell` to load the Django environment.